# Same-origin policy blocking API request on remote

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy

The "on remote" section is why I am confused on this. I am trying to do a POST request to `https://api.smarkets.com/v3/sessions`. The route is to create a session token for subsequent requests to the API.

If I do this request on my local machine, it works fine. I get a 2xx response. However, if I try on a remote machine (*DO box I spun up last night*), I get a '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable' response.

I attempted to login via the browser & I got the same response. I [raised this question to Smarkets](https://community.smarkets.com/t/login-issues-503/410/3) & they eluded to the fact it might be due to the same-origin policy imposed by Smarkets.

After some time, I managed to login via Chrome by disabling the same-origin policy. The API request still failed.

From my limited knowledge of the same-origin policy (*please correct me if I'm wrong*), it specifies what resources are allowed to be returned from certain origins. Similar to CORS issues. Why would I have to explicitly disable web security on a remote browser to get it to login to smarkets.com but my browser on my local machine can login just fine without being modified?

The question I highlighted above shows what methods I have tried to get this to work. No matter what request headers I attempt to set, the response headers are always the same with `X-Frame-Options` response header always set to `SAMEORIGIN` which, *again from what I understand*, only allows resources to be sent to the same origin of the sender. I.e. resources sent from smarkets.com can only be accessed by requests from smarkets.com.

My current request attempt is (*with `httpie`*):

```
http POST https://api.smarkets.com/v3/sessions/ 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Host, Origin' 'Access-Control-Request-Methods: POST, OPTIONS' 'Origin: https://smarkets.com' username=<username> password=<password> --print=Hh
```

The request & response headers are:

[image: Failed headers]

I'm really looking for;

- Clarity on what the same-origin policy is imposing
- Why does this request succeed on my local machine but not a remote DO box
- How can I get this request to succeed?

The user at Smarkets seems like this is a same-origin issue but it might not be.

**EDIT:**

It's not a firewall issue as I disabled Ubuntu's built-in firewall. I am doing other requests over http(s) from the same origin so I can't figure out what is different about this one

**EDIT 2:**

Below is an example of successful request/response headers:

[image: Successful headers]

I'm able to make other API calls from the same box to different origins, including:

- `https://api.betdaq.com`
- `https://api.betfair.com`
- `https://api.matchbook.com`

I have added no configurations specifically around any origins on the box so am really unsure as to what this issue is. I have added all the possible CORS request headers that I can think of & still no luck.

**EDIT 3:**

Annoyingly, this has been fixed now as the vendors API blacklists DigitalOcean IPs by default...

Answer (score 4):

Cors is both a server and a client thing. The servers defines the policiy, a client COULD enforce it. Browsers, for example, do enforce it because it is more safe (not going into the detail here). Therefore disabling same-origin policy in you browser or using an untrusted browser is a security issue.

Again, the client COULD enforce the policy. As far as I know most commandline http clients do not enforce it. That could explain why your httpie request does not fail.

From a browser perspective, you cannot resolve the problem. Again, it is the server that defines the policy. What you can do is create a proxy server. You van specify your own cors policy. The brower makes request to your proxyserver. Your proxyserver passes the reqeust to the actual server.

Answer (score 0):

Cors is more or less always a server side thing. If the vendor is exposing some api to hit then they should make sure that cors is disabled. Other than talking to them about it, you really can do nothing else from your side. Having to disable cors from chrome is a bad idea.